# symfony 3 twig template function if

Tags: javascript, php, twig, symfony

this function

```
function test(){
         var distance =calculateHaversineFormula({{lat}}, {{lng}},{{  geocode.latitude}}, {{ geocode.longitude }} );
                    {%  if distance < 1000 %}
                    console.log(distance);
                    {%  endif  %}

    }
```

function calculate.. returns d (distance), so I want to make constant for this.. then i want to filtrate to get all distances who has less than 1000, but I got error Variable "distance" does not exist in default\index.html.twig at line 41.

Without if

```
 var distance =calculateHaversineFormula({{lat}}, {{lng}},{{  geocode.latitude}}, {{ geocode.longitude }} ); 
            console.log(distance);
```

This works fine..  So what is wrong with if?

Comment: You set up distance variable in JavaScript code and then try to check it in TWIG if statement, Of course TWIG do not know anything about distance TWIG variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to rewrite your condition in JS, like so:

```
function test(){
  var distance =calculateHaversineFormula({{lat}}, {{lng}},{{geocode.latitude}}, {{ geocode.longitude }} );
  if distance < 1000 {
    console.log(distance);
  }
}
```